# Save Zoomed image and send it to server after zooming

Tags: ios, objective-c, zooming

My question is related to zooming image. I am using YKImageCropper [this](https://github.com/yuyak/YKImageCropper) code for zooming  image i want to save image afater zooming so that i can send that image to server and on server side they will apply same scale as i have applied and get the same image as i have created on my device. My app is basically for creating template of photo on T shirt and server side they will get this template and they will apply same filters and get ready for tshirt printing. Let me know if you don't understand the flow. 
I can do this thing by two way 
1) By saving zoomed image

2) apply scale on original image

Please help me out

Thanks in Advance

```
- (UIImage *)editedImage {
    CGFloat scale = self.image.size.width / self.imageView.frame.size.width;
    CGRect rect = self.overlayView.clearRect;
    rect.origin.x = (rect.origin.x - self.imageView.frame.origin.x) * scale;
    rect.origin.y = (rect.origin.y - self.imageView.frame.origin.y) * scale;
    rect.size.width *= scale;
    rect.size.height *= scale;
    NSLog(@"scale ::: %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(rect.origin));
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClipToRect(c, CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height));
    [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(-rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y, self.image.size.width, self.image.size.height)];
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: you need us to tell which of options 1 or 2 is best? or any problem with code? Obviously 2 is preferred, because the synchronisation can be fast as you dont need to send 1MB(say) of image to server every time he changes the crop.

Comment: @santhu i want to Check the first option and save zoomed image let me know if you have any solution regarding that

Answer (score 0):

using the **YKImageCropper** to crop an image(in your terms zoomed),

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sample.jpg"];
YKImageCropperViewController *vc = [[YKImageCropperViewController alloc] initWithImage:image];
vc.cancelHandler = ^() {
    // When cancel is tapped
};
vc.doneHandler = ^(UIImage *editedImage) {
    // editedImage supplied here is your zoomed image
    // do something with edited image and save it to server.
};
```

**doneHandler** is a **block** that you pass to get the image after cropping and using it.
Hope this helps.

Comment: that i know but i need whole zoomed image instead of small part or box  @santhu

Comment: is there a zoom feature in YKImageCropper.?

Comment: YKImageCropper is specially designed for cropping. If you just need to zoom the image, and have screenshot of the zoomed image, you should go with UIScrollView . Or else you have to edit his code, tweak a little bit.